# How to jump to a term in a page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
HyperText Markup 
<span style="background-color:#E06685;" name="31245">
  <b>Language</b>
</span>
, commonly referred to as HTML, is the standard markup 
<span style="background-color:#E06685;" name="31245">
  <b>language</b>
</span>
used to create 
<span name="41245" style="color:#027a00;font-weight:bold">
  web
</span>
pages.[1] 
<span name="41245" style="color:#027a00;font-weight:bold">
  Web
</span>
browsers can read HTML files and render them into visible or audible 
<span name="41245" style="color:#027a00;font-weight:bold">
  web
</span>
pages.
```

This is some text in the html page and the page has some span tags with name attribute.The name attribute will have same value for all the occurences of particular term.
In the above text we have span with name as '31245' corresponding to 'language' word and '41245' corresponding to 'web'.In the same page we have a dropdown showing all the unique words of the span tag. User can select one word from dorpdown and can navigate to the occurences of selected word in the html page by using next button.
This is similar to the search functionality(Ctrl+F) in PDF for instance.
Can someone tell how to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: use anchor tag with href..

Comment: You can't re-use IDs...they need to be unique on a page.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Comment: @Paulie_D : I have renamed 'id' to 'name'. Please refer to my below comment for info. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your href link put websiteurl+"#[id]"

This will jump to the [id] of the element you put that id on.

**Demonstration**

```html
<a href="#lorem1">Go to Lorem #1</a>
<br/>
<a href="#lorem2">Go to Lorem #2</a>
<br/>
<a href="#lorem3">Go to Lorem #3</a>
<br/>

<div>
  <h3 id="lorem1"><b>Lorem Paragraph #1</b></h3>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque a tortor vulputate ante ultricies sodales pretium quis augue. Suspendisse quis enim dignissim, pretium elit sit amet, vestibulum elit. Etiam non consectetur ante, sed volutpat mauris. Fusce
  vestibulum orci ligula, sit amet dapibus quam laoreet id. Aenean dignissim, felis quis consectetur rhoncus, est quam volutpat ex, at interdum nisi ligula ac arcu. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean tincidunt maximus nisl, vel congue ipsum viverra vel. Suspendisse
  eget magna eu purus sagittis luctus. Maecenas eleifend at neque at ullamcorper. Nullam semper elit augue, eu pretium tortor congue quis. Morbi gravida semper odio. Duis faucibus ut eros nec suscipit. Proin diam nibh, efficitur at efficitur nec, posuere
  id lacus. Quisque vel tortor vehicula, efficitur mi eget, volutpat nunc. Aenean porta orci at malesuada luctus.

</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div>
  <h3 id="lorem2"><b>Lorem Paragraph #2</b></h3>
  In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla sem magna, cursus in elementum in, ultricies vel velit. Mauris lacinia maximus metus sit amet iaculis. Fusce sed magna tempus, semper ligula ornare, sodales nisl. Vestibulum id neque ut erat pharetra mattis eu sit
  amet nibh. Vivamus ornare justo semper mi fringilla feugiat. Donec ultrices velit dui, a mollis sapien suscipit id. Maecenas congue urna vel justo pulvinar lacinia. Nam non diam commodo, ultricies nulla molestie, dapibus mi. Fusce in lacus sem. Donec
  nisl enim, ullamcorper sit amet rutrum vulputate, pretium at sapien. Nullam vitae tincidunt sapien, sed sollicitudin magna.

</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<div>
  <h3 id="lorem3"><b>Lorem Paragraph #3</b></h3>
  Donec tempor ullamcorper quam, eu fringilla diam egestas ut. Etiam eros purus, scelerisque vitae elit id, consectetur congue magna. Etiam in neque quis mauris scelerisque efficitur. Cras et sapien justo. Nam sed ligula metus. Vestibulum gravida eros id
  mi dapibus dapibus. Aliquam lectus dolor, pulvinar vel magna et, rutrum vehicula ante. Pellentesque nisi ipsum, sodales nec dolor id, sodales varius magna. Donec feugiat placerat egestas. Morbi quis magna nec velit auctor bibendum. Vivamus metus magna,
  pellentesque sit amet est ut, dapibus hendrerit risus. Proin vel nulla lacus. Proin lacinia felis sit amet augue dictum, sit amet aliquam velit posuere. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed ac justo justo.



</div>
```

Comment: Except in this case where the same ID is used repeatedly on multiple elements - it will only jump to the first match it finds.

Comment: Thank you Senta, but this is not my requirement. To reiterate, assume I have a paragraph on my html page, a dropdown with some key words from the paragraph and a next button. For example, my paragraph has 10 occurrences  of term 'language' which is one among the key word in the drop down. When user selects 'language' from dropdown and subsequently clicks on next button, the user should be navigated to each occurrence of the term within one by one within the paragraph. This is similar to the search functionality(Ctrl+F) in PDF for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it effectively and dynamically...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".menu").on("click",function(event) {
    
   if ($(".toggleMenu").hasClass('active')) {
   
    $(".toggleMenu").click();
   }
   $('html,body').animate({ 
   scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
   
   });
            
   $(".chosen-select").chosen();
         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#div1" class="menu">First</a></li>
        
        <li> <a href="#div2" class="menu">Second</a></li>
        
        <li> <a href="#div3" class="menu">Third</a></li>
        
        <li> <a href="#div4" class="menu">Forth</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section style="height:150px;width:100%;" id="div1">
    <h2 style="text-center">First Div</h2>    
</section>

<section style="height:150px;width:100%;" id="div2">
    <h2 style="text-center">Second Div</h2>
</section>

<section style="height:150px;width:100%;" id="div3">
    <h2 style="text-center">Third Div</h2>
</section>

<section style="height:150px;width:100%;" id="div4">
    <h2 style="text-center">Forth Div</h2>
</section>
```